# e.preventDefault with ajax stopping my form action code working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having some trouble getting a form to properly email its contents to me, using ajax to show a thank you message rather than reload. Removing preventDefault() from the JS gets the form to send correctly, but obviously also causes a page redirect to the PHP file, which I don't want. Code included below, is there something obvious I've done wrong? Site is running on Wordpress, but I don't want to use a plugin as these seem to add extra elements that break the form design.

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/review-form-handler.php" id="websiteReviewForm">
    <div class="formField">
        <div class="inputEffect">
            <input type="text" name="Website" required>
            <hr>
            <label for="Website">Your Website?</label>
        </div>
        <p>1 / 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="formField">
        <div class="inputEffect">
            <input type="text" name="Name" required>
            <hr>
            <label for="Name">Your Name?</label>
        </div>
        <p>2 / 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="formField">
        <div class="inputEffect">
            <input type="text" name="Email" required>
            <hr>
            <label for="Email">Your Email?</label>
        </div>
        <p>3 / 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="formField">
        <div class="inputEffect">
            <input type="text" name="Phone" required>
            <hr>
            <label for="Phone">Your Phone Number?</label>
        </div>
        <p>4 / 4</p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="REVIEW MY WEBSITE">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('#websiteReviewForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:$(this).attr('action'),
        type:'post',
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        success:function(){
           $('#websiteReviewForm').hide();
           $('.thankyouMessage').show();
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {

$recipient="MY EMAIL";
$subject="Form to email message";
$sender="Visix";
$senderEmail="MY EMAIL";
$website=$_POST["Website"];
$name=$_POST["Name"];
$email=$_POST["Email"];
$number=$_POST["Number"];

$mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\nWebsite: $website\nName: $name\nEmail: $email\nPhone number: $number";

mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");
}

?>
```

Comment: *"I'm having some trouble getting a form to properly email its contents to me"* Forms don't **email** their contents anywhere.

Comment: Excellent job providing all the necessary information to answer the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you're checking for the form in the PHP:

```
if($_POST["submit"]) {
```

Since you're not posting it via the normal mechanism trigged by the submit button, there's no `submit` entry in the data sent to the server. (The value of a `submit` button is only sent when the form is actually submitted via that button's activation.)

You can solve that by

1. Adding

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="x">
   ```

   ...to the form
2. **Or** adding it in the `ajax` call after serializing:

   ```
   data: $(this).serialize() + "&submit=x",
   ```
3. **Or** just checking for one or more of the other fields that already exist

Comment: Thank you so much for the speedy response :-) problem solved!